# DNS probe failed, no internet

Tags: android

I have installed orbit on my android, first the transproxy doesn't work, even using default iptables, or other iptables with orbit, the browser shows connected to tour, but cannot open any onion sites. I also tried proxydroid to use proxy on chrome, but still it shows me connected but no onion sites open. The only way is to use the APN trick, to create a new APN with the proxy and port of orbit. This way the onion sites open, but I don't want to use for for every app, which this APN does. So is there a way to use it for specific app.